# Basic Perl hash sorting by key, by value, but also by key AND value

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

Okay, I have a Perl program I'm writing which has a hash of values that I have collected (in a whole separate program altogether) and have fed to this Perl script.  This hash is a hash of (string,string).

I want to sort the values 3 ways: First, I want to sort by key.  I figured this is easy, you do it exactly the way you would think, using Perl's built in sort function, looping over the keys, and printing/storing/whatevering with each one as they are sorted.

```
foreach my $name (sort keys %planets) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $name, $planets{$name};
}
```

Second, I want to sort by value.  Again, this is easy, use the sort function and loop over:

```
foreach my $name (sort { $planets{$a} <=> $planets{$b} } keys %planets) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $name, $planets{$name};
}
```

Third, **My question** is, how do I sort by value, but for any *ties* in values between two keys, I sort out first the value which has the greater Asciibetical key.  Example:

```
Red => 50
Yellow => 75
Blue => 75

is sorted to this, since 'Yellow' is greater asciibetically than 'Blue' 
Red 50
Blue 75
Yellow 75
```

Answer (score 10):

On a tie, the comparison operators will return 0, so you can chain several comparisons with `||`:

```
 sort { $planets{$a} <=> $planets{$b} || $a cmp $b }
```

Comment: Hey, taking a look at this now.  Your answer is being read and considered!